# Random Segmentation Fault - Raspberry Pi, C++, MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, raspberry-pi

I'm having an issue with segmentation faults crashing my c++ program. I've narrowed it down to executing mysql queries. If I remove the query it never crashes but when it does run the query it may work 5 times in a row and crash or it might go 20 times before a segmentation fault, it's very random.

This is the code to connect.

```
MYSQL *conn;
void connectMysql(){

    const char *server = "localhost";
    const char *user = "root";
    const char *password = "myPpassword";
    const char *database = "myDatabase";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
        user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Then I do this to run my queries. It'll happen with other queries as well.

```
connectMysql();
std::string query = "UPDATE settings SET tempFormat = '" + to_string(tempFormat) + "'";
std::cout << query << std::endl;  // print string to terminal
mysql_query(conn, query.c_str());
std::cout << "done" << std::endl;  // print done to terminal
mysql_close(conn);
```

Using std::cout to write to terminal it looks like it's happening with mysql_query function. I print the query string to terminal and that always looks good going into mysql_query even when it crashes. When it does crash I never see the "done" printed to terminal so it doesn't make it that far.

I've just recently discovered this as I don't save to database that often so not exactly sure what c++ mysql library I'm using but this is what I use to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev -y
```

Thanks

Comment: Just because this is where your program crashes doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in your program, but the program continues running and doesn't crash immediately until it attempts to use memory corrupted by the bug, and then it crashes at that point. Connecting and disconnecting from mysql is a fairly complicated process, so it's not surprising that it likely to weed out bugs like that. You will need to find the real bug, and fix it.

Comment: Try putting your code in this form, and see if you are getting some error: ```if(mysql_query(conn, query.c_str())) std::cerr << mysql_error(conn);```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still same issue and no error printed, just says segmentation fault.